# How to redirect to back after signing completion in docuSign

Tags: javascript, node.js, docusignapi, electronic-signature

I'm trying to embedded signing workflow through this API http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning

after successfully execution of this I got this response

```
API Call Result:  { url: 'https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?t=sdf34f6-8592-4250-83a8-4bf34f5g3t' }

Navigate to the above URL to start the Embedded Signing workflow...
```

I opened this url in browser manually and tried to sign. after singing it asked to click on finish to complete this process(as obvious). but when I click on this it redirect to http://www.docusign.com/developer-center?event=signing_complete  but I want something so that I can decide callback URL, I mean url which I want to redirect to. In my case I would like to redirect to my application's home page ttp://www.myapp.com/

How could I achieve that using the V2 REST API?

Answer (score 4):

To specify where the browser redirects when the signing session ends, you simply set the `returnUrl` parameter in the **POST Recipient View** API request (i.e., the request that you sent to DocuSign in order to receive the URL to launch the Signing Session).  See page 167 of the REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) for a description of this parameter -- including the possible values of the **event** querystring parameter that DocuSign will add onto the end of the **returnUrl** that you specify.  Your application's landing page (i.e., represented by `returnUrl`) can use the value of the **event** parameter to know the outcome of the signing session, and display the appropriate messaging, etc.