# Docusign ReturnURL using SOAP API

Tags: soap, docusignapi

Seeing lots of un-answered Docusign questions, but I'll take the chance anyway.

I see lots of examples of how you can use the returnURL parameter using the Docusign REST api in order to redirect a user to a custom URL upon completion of signing. For example: [How to redirect to back after signing completion in docuSign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147493/how-to-redirect-to-back-after-signing-completion-in-docusign)

Nowhere can I find a similar setting when using the [Docusign SOAP API](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm). Perhaps someone out in the stack universe knows more? Maybe someone is a better googler than I?

Answer (score 0):

It will always be found in the RequestToken, whether it's for sender, recipient, correct, etc. Info [here](https://www.docusign.com.au/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Embedding%20Group/Pre-DocuSign%20Operations.htm?)